Address mismatch in Driving Licence and IDP: Is it a problem
I recently applied for an IDP from the Automobile Association of India for my trip to Japan, and they issued me a booklet one too.
My issue is that all my documents, but my driving license are on my latest address.
Specifically, the address on my DL is of my previous residence but my IDP (and passport too) is on my latest residence.
Really not sure if I will be able to rent a car with this IDP in Japan or not. Can they argue that the address of DL and IDP should match? Heard that they really strict with the guidelines in Japan.
I have already made the bookings for car (Toyota rentals) and hotel, but if the car shop denied at the last moment, it will be disheartening and obviously a waste of money too.
I thought of getting my DL updated, but is really tough given the time constraints I have.
Requesting you guys to share your thoughts/solutions.
Thanks in advance!

It's fine. Your address is not a mandatory part of a driver's license, in many countries (eg much of the EU) it's not included at all.

I see. Japanese people are somewhat stringent on the rules, I am scared they might point it! Is there anything that can be done

@Ninjahattori The IDP requires a current and valid drivers license; if your license is indeed current and valid, you are not in violation of the rules. If they ask about the discrepancy (extremely unlikely, IMO) just tell them the real reason (e.g. you've changed addresses since your license was issued, and India does not require updating the license for change of address.)
